Nomenclature of car wheel parts
I routinely have difficulty describing these terms when talking about car wheels.
In cycling the distinction is pretty obvious, as the parts are manufactured separately. A rim is the outer part — often an aluminum alloy; the spokes are the long skewers — made of steel or carbon, but never of aluminum; (and the nipples are the small joints between them). The tire is the rubber part, and the wheel is the hub+spokes+rim+tire.
If, in the context of cars, I say "tire" (or "tyre"), everyone knows I still mean the rubber part. But how otherwise can I refer unambiguously to rim, spokes, and the "entire thing"?
Also, specifically, does a car's rim include the spokes? If it does, how can I refer to the part aside from the spokes?
In case it matters, I'm seeking the answer in American/Canadian English.

Car wheel nomenclature historically derives from bicycles and from the animal-powered transport.
Tire/tyre is the rubber part, no ambiguities.
Rim + spokes are an integral part in modern cars, called simply "rim". Spokes may still be referred when discussing the rim geometry.
In the past, this was not always the case, first motor cars did have spokes just like modern bicycles and motorbikes.
Tyre + rim = wheel.
The hub in a modern car is the part where the rim bolts onto. When you remove the wheel, you see the hub, usually partially covered by the brake disc or drum.
In the offroad car parlance, "hub" is sometimes the part that transfers the movement between the axle shaft and the actual hub.

In America, the entire thing is "wheel" and "rim" is the outer part.  You seem to understand the terms well.
I think the difficulty you might be noticing is how youthful drivers use loose slang.  "I put some hot rims on my car" refers to more expensive aftermarket wheels, usually wider and larger than factory specifications.  Such examples are not meant to be precise and technical, more a matter of emphasizing the rim portion of wheel which is usually highly polished or a different color.

To complete the present Q&A, and while we're talking about wheels, notice also the following names of the tire tread parts:

The four main parts of tire tread patterns are:

Ribs - raised section on the footprint that is usually made up using
blocks
Grooves - various circumferential and lateral grooves are
channels in the tread patterns
Blocks - rubber segments located on the
footprint, making contact with the road
Sipes - thin slots on the
tread area that provide extra biting edges


